# Unable to open gedit over sshx as root

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, xauth

I'm doing an remote login using sshx -X as root:

```
ssh -X root@172.16.0.1
```

After that whatever application I open, a warning is coming like:

> X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
>   Blockquote

Still the application is opening. I've opened `nautilus, firefox, opera, idle`. All are opening regardless the warning. But when I open `gedit` the application is not opening after that warning and I'm being returned to my prompt.

I searched on-line and I'm getting for specific user how to provide x-auth. Since I'm logging in as a root user, I should be able to open any application.

Why it's saying wrong authentication?

Comment: Do your sshd config files (usually /etc/ssh/sshd_config) have `X11Forwarding` set to `yes`? Also take a look at: [Run application on local machine and show GUI on remote display](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203173/run-application-on-local-machine-and-show-gui-on-remote-display)

Comment: @JonnyHenly It's set to `No`. How is it affecting to this?

Comment: @RatDon The server doesn't allow you to forward X11 packets back through your SSH session. See http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config section X11Forwarding.

Comment: @mtak Then how come I'm able to run all the applications except gedit? I tried nautilus, firefox, opera even idle. Except gedit all are opening.

Comment: That is very useful info to put in your question, please update it with this information so people don't have to look through the comment section looking for vital information.

Comment: @mtak I mentioned as whatever application. But yeah will update the with the names. it'll be useful. :D